# Segfault 11 binary tree paths

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I have to make a function in **C++** that finds the **external path** and the **internal path** of a binary tree and prints them. I'm having trouble with a segfault 11 once the function for finding the paths is called, but I can't figure out where the segfault is. I don't have a very clear understanding of what a segfault is, all I know is that the program is trying to access a chunk of memory that's not available. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Nodo
{   
    friend class Albero;
    Nodo (int);
    int valore;
    Nodo *prev;
    Nodo *next;
};

Nodo :: Nodo (int num)
{
    valore = num;
    prev = 0;
    next = 0;
};

class Albero
{
    public:
        Albero ();
        void inserisci (int);     // insertion of a value;
        void trovaCammino (int&, int&, int);    // find path
        void stampa ();        //print
    private:
        Nodo *radice;          // first item
        void stampaRicorsivo (Nodo*);
        void inserisciRicorsivo (Nodo *&, int);
        void trovaCamminoRic (Nodo*&, int&, int&, int);
};

Albero :: Albero ()
{
    radice = 0;
};

void Albero :: inserisci (int nuovo)
{
    inserisciRicorsivo (radice, nuovo);
};

void Albero :: inserisciRicorsivo (Nodo*& radice, int nuovo)
{
    if (radice == 0)
    {
        radice = new Nodo (nuovo);
    } else if (nuovo < radice->valore)
        {
            inserisciRicorsivo(radice->prev, nuovo);
        } else if (nuovo > radice->valore)
            {
                inserisciRicorsivo(radice->next, nuovo);
            }
};

void Albero :: trovaCammino (int& contInt, int& contEst, int curr)
{
    trovaCamminoRic(radice, contInt, contEst, curr);
};

void Albero :: trovaCamminoRic (Nodo*& radice, int& contInt, int& contEst, int curr)
{
    if (radice->prev != 0)              // if previous element is present
    {
        curr++;                         // increase current level
        contInt++;                      // increase internal path counter
        trovaCamminoRic(radice->prev, contInt, contEst, curr);          // call it again on the previous element
    } else if (radice->next != 0)       // if next element is present...
    {
        curr++;
        contInt++;
        trovaCamminoRic(radice->prev, contInt, contEst, curr);
    } else              // if both are untrue, which means that the node is a leaf
    {
        contEst = (contEst+curr);       // increase the external counter
        contInt--;                      // decrease the internal counter by one;
    }
};

void Albero :: stampa ()
{
    stampaRicorsivo (radice);
};

void Albero :: stampaRicorsivo (Nodo* radice)
{
    if (radice != 0)
    {
        stampaRicorsivo (radice->prev);
        cout << radice->valore << endl;
        stampaRicorsivo(radice->next);
    }
;}

int main ()
{
    int curr;
    curr = 0;
    Albero rami;
    int dim;
    cout << "Inserire la grandezza dell'albero che si vuole generare"; cin >> dim;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        int num; 
        cout << "Inserire il valore n° " << (i+1) << ": "; cin >> num;
        rami.inserisci(num);
    }
    int contInt = 0;
    int contEst = 0;
    rami.stampa();
    rami.trovaCammino(contInt, contEst, curr);
    cout << "Il cammino interno dell'albero è: " << contInt << endl << "Il cammino esterno dell'albero è: " << contEst << endl;
}
```

Comment: Use a *debugger* to catch the crash as it happens. It will allow you to examine the function call stack to see when and where in your code the crash happens, and also let you examine variables to see their values.

Comment: If you are using `g++` and compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` it'll tell you exactly where it crashes when you run the program and it's in `Albero::trovaCamminoRic` at `if(radice->prev != 0)` when `radice` is `nullptr`.

Comment: [Edit] and show an example of input that triggers the problem. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `trovaCamminoRic`, `radice` can be NULL, but you don't check that, and dereferencing NULL like in `radice->prev` is undefined behaviour, which usually crashes your program with a segfault.

Simply add this check and it should work:

```
void Albero::trovaCamminoRic(Nodo*& radice, int& contInt, int& contEst, int curr)
{
  if (radice == NULL)
    return;
  ...
```

You should invest an hour or so in learning the basics of your debugger. With a debugger you find this kind of problems in minutes.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not sure what the program is supposed to do, and there may be other problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, I should indeed understand how to use the debugger, I have only started to use in the last few days so I guess I'm going to have to tinker with it helped by some videos. Again, thank you very much, this solved the issue